# print number of student in each class - drupal view

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have drupal view for displaying our classes, we need to print in each row the number of students in each class.

Is this applicable in drupal view?

```
[class name]    [desc.]        [No. of students]
class1          class1 desc    40
```

Comment: Yes views can do this but I can't possibly tell you how if with the limited information you just gave.

Comment: I have classes content type and students user role and link table between them what I want to display # of student in each class as my example above.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "link table between them" did you make a custom table? If so you will need to write views handlers for the relationship.

Comment: You will probably create a user based view with the aggregate function to count the results. Entity reference could be used to track the users back to their class and the aggrogate will count the users instead of listing them all. Can't help much more without actually working on the system but hopefully that puts you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of view can be created with combination of [Nodereference Count](http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_count) and [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) modules.

First you need to download and enable these two modules.

Create a node reference field in student content type which refers to class node.

Now in class content type create 'No. of students' field with 'Node reference count' field type to store count of node references in student content type which you will select while configuring this node reference count field.

Now in your view of class content type you can add 'No. of students' field to show number of students which were refereed to this class.

But this will not work of existing nodes as you have to update these nodes individually or by [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module.